# F# try with unhandled exceptions

Tags: f#

In the following code, I want to read a file and return all lines; if there is IO error, I want the program exit with error message print to console. But the program still run into unhandled exception.  What's the best practice for this? (I guess I dont need `Some/None` since I want to the program exit at error anyway.) thanks.

```
let lines = 
    try 
      IO.File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
    with
    | ex -> failwithf " %s" ex.Message
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do type test pattern matching.

```
let lines = 
    try 
      IO.File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
    with
    | :? System.IO.IOException as e ->
        printfn " %s" e.Message
        // This will terminate the program
        System.Environment.Exit e.HResult
        // We have to yield control or return a string array
        Array.empty
    | ex -> failwithf " %s" ex.Message
```

Comment: If I use printfn, how to exit program after?

Comment: @user8321 - When you call `failwithf` you are raising a new exception. Sure you don't want to use `printfn`?

Comment: @user8321 - Well the thing is if you exit the program, printing to the console will be pretty meaningless.

Comment: Thanks. a minor issue is that e.HResult is not accessible. I was thinking to redirect the console to a log file. Do you have a better workflow for this?

Comment: @user8321 - You could write to the windows event log before you exit the program. (Don't worry about the HResult property, you can just replace it with 0.)