# log4net and "with try" F#

Tags: f#, log4net, try-with-resources

I am using log4net in a try with expression and it is not working. I think something is missing but I don't know what.
Here is my code :

```
let clusterIDArray = try
                         myfunction
                     with
                         log.Fatal("my function is not working")   


log.Debug("my function is working")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't catch exceptions. I think `try myfunction with _ -> log.Fatal("my function is not working")` would work.

Comment: Thanks pad you are totally right. Moreover, i found something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972436/f-try-with-unhandled-exceptions. Sorry for the almost duplicated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code snippet:

- You didn't execute your function. I suppose that you did execute it in your real code; it's the matter of making up an example.
- You didn't catch exceptions or your `try...with...` block is not syntactically correct.

Assuming that we catch exceptions and return an array in any case, a more idiomatic way of logging could be:

```
let clusterIDArray =
    try
       let result = myfunction args // Assume args are arguments declared before
       log.Debug("my function is working")
       result
    with 
    | ex ->
       // ex is of type exception which can be parsed by log4net
       log.Fatal("my function is not working: ", ex)   
       [||]
```

Comment: Thanks Pad. An issue here is that result as an Array type whereas the log.Fatal as a type Unit which seems to be a problem when I write it. I want to stop the execution of the code in case of the exception, but I don't know how to return a Array type in the exception case.

Comment: Just return an empty array `[||]` in the line after `log.Fatal`. I suggest that you include the exception's stacktrace into the log, so that you know which causes the problem.

Comment: I suggest using `log.Fatal("not working", ex)`. Log4net can parse the exception and print the stack trace if required.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say without knowing what the `myfunction` is, but as you wrote it, the code does not actually *run* the function. It simply returns it as a value (from the `try .. with` block) and assigns it to the `clusterIDArray` value, so the code will never throw.

If the function takes just a `unit` argument, you can call it inside the `try .. with` block like this (if it takes some arguments, you'll need to give them to the function inside the block):

```
let clusterIDarray = 
  try 
    myfunction ()
  with _ ->
    log.Fatal("not working")
    reraise() // You still need to return something here or rethrow the exception

log.Debug("my function is working")
```

**EDIT** As others noted, the syntax `with e` is not valid. You need to write `with e ->` or `with _ ->` if you want to ignore the exception.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. In fact I was not very clear, my function takes a string as an argument and return an array (clusterViewName |> readDSLClusterID). So do I need to return the same type (i.e. an array) in the "with" part? I am trying something like let clusterIDArray = try
                            clusterViewName |> readDSLClusterID
                         with
                         | :? Exception ->   log.Fatal("ClustersID not downloaded")

Comment: Yes, you either have to return an empty array (i.e. using `[| |]` ) or you need to call `reraise()` which rethrows the exception without returning.

Comment: Once again Thank you Thomas and Pad for your answers, it's working and it's very clear for me now.